# Java Update Existing Excel File

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to write a program that will update existing Excel file.The problem i am having is it had not append texts to the file.Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class LC_negotiation {

  public static void LC_negotiation(){
    try { 
      FileInputStream file = 
        new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\home.xls"));
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      Cell cell = null;
      cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
      cell.setCellValue("Name");
      cell = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(2);
      cell.setCellValue("Address");
      file.close();
      FileOutputStream outFile =
        new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\home.xls"));
      workbook.write(outFile);
      outFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    LC_negotiation lc_one = new LC_negotiation();
  }

}
```

Comment: Q: Are you saying the original .xls is unchanged?  That "Name" and "Address" aren't present in either the original or the updated files?  Q: Have you stepped through the debugger, and verified that "workbook", "sheet" and "cell" are getting assigned the correct values?

Comment: yes, it can't append "Name","address" to home.xls

Comment: Not "can't".  "Doesn't" ;)  Your next step: examine the execution under the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems with the above code, including:

a) The constructor should be defined as a constructor.

b) If the spreadsheet doesn't already have rows and columns, then you must create them.

c) You need to "close()" your workbook

Here's an example of creating your spreadsheet from scratch.  Changes needed to update an existing spreadsheet should be pretty straightforward:

```
package com.test.hellopoi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class LC_negotiation {

  public static final String TEST_FILE = "tests/test.xls";

  public LC_negotiation(){
    try { 
      // Create Excel-95 spreadsheet
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

      HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);     
      Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
      cell.setCellValue("Name");

      row = sheet.createRow(2);     
      cell = row.createCell(2);
      cell.setCellValue("Address");

      FileOutputStream outFile =
        new FileOutputStream(new File(TEST_FILE));
      workbook.write(outFile);
      workbook.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    LC_negotiation lc_one = new LC_negotiation();
  }

}
```

Comment: @Chang Yangshin - Q: Did you get your code working?  Was the sample above helpful?  Do you have any additional questions?